# shell sort command : How to sort by the last column (the number of columns is uncertain)?

Tags: bash, shell, sorting

If the data is like the follow:

```
a,b,3
c,d,e,f,2
g,1
```

I want sort by the last column. the result should be:

```
g,1
c,d,e,f,2
a,b,3
```

Comment: or is there another way ?

Comment: Pipe it to another command (like `awk`) that copies the last column to the front,  pipe that to `sort`, then pipe that to another command that removes the first column.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16593463/unix-sort-using-unknown-delimiter-last-column

Answer (score 3):

if the last field is single digit

```
$ rev file | sort | rev
```

you may need to add `-t, -n` to sort for numerical ordering but single digits it doesn't matter.

or, for the general case with `awk`

```
$ awk -F, '{a[$NF]=$0} END{n=asorti(a,d); for(k=1;k<=n;k++) print a[d[k]]}' file

g,1
c,d,e,f,2
a,b,3
```

This will fail if the last field is not unique.  Using **decorate/sort/undecorate** idiom you can write instead (as you found yourself)

```
$ awk -F, '{print $NF FS $0}' file | sort -n | cut -d, -f2-
```

it's safer to use the field delimiter between the key and the record since you want to ensure the FS doesn't appear in the key itself.

Comment: but, If there are duplicate numbers, the result seems to be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I have a stupid but simple way to do it :)

> // if original data in the file : ~/Desktop/1.log
>
> $ awk -F, '{print $NF, $0}'  ~/Desktop/1.log  | sort -n | awk '{print $2}'
>
> g,1
>
> c,d,e,f,2
>
> a,b,3

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution using bash script -- i named it `uncertain.sh`.

```bash
# Set here the size of the largest item to sort.
# In our case it is c,d,e,f,2 which is size 5.
max_n=5

# This function 'pads' array with P's before last element
# to force it to grow to max_n size.
# For example, (a b 3) will be transformed into (a b P P 3).
pad () {
    local arr=("$@")
    local l=${#arr[@]}
    local diff_l=$((max_n-l))

    local padding=""

    # construct padding
    for i in `seq 1 $diff_l`; do
    padding+="P "
    done

    local l_minus=$((l-1))
    arr=(${arr[@]:0:$l_minus} "$padding"${arr[@]:$l_minus})

    echo "${arr[@]}"
}

################################################
# Provide A,B,C here to sort by last item
################################################
A="a,b,3"
B="c,d,e,f,2"
C="g,1"

A=$(echo "$A" | tr ',' ' ')
B=$(echo "$B" | tr ',' ' ')
C=$(echo "$C" | tr ',' ' ')

a=(`echo "$A"`)
b=(`echo "$B"`)
c=(`echo "$C"`)

# Get padded arrays.
a=$(pad "${a[@]}")
b=$(pad "${b[@]}")
c=$(pad "${c[@]}")

# Here, we sort by the last field (we can do this since
# padded arrays are all same size 5).
# Then we remove 'P's from strings.
feed=$(printf "%s\n" "$a" "$b" "$c" | sort -k5,5n | tr -d 'P')

# Lastly, we change spaces with commas ','.
while read line; do
    echo "$line" | tr -s ' ' | tr ' ' ','
done < <(echo "$feed")
```

Here's the output

```
$ ./uncertain.sh
g,1
c,d,e,f,2
a,b,3
```

Here's how I did it:

We start with

```
a,b,3
c,d,e,f,2
g,1
```

We convert this to

```
a,b,P,P,3
c,d,e,f,2
g,P,P,P,1
```

Then we can sort by the 5th column since they are all of same size 5.

So this becomes

```
g,P,P,P,1
c,d,e,f,2
a,b,P,P,3
```

We can now remove P's.

```
g,1
c,d,e,f,2
a,b,3
```

Hope you found this useful.